# CASE..WHEN condition not working in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case-when

I have below `case when` condition in query which is not getting somehow satisfied.

I want to write logic in `case when` in `select` query such that when `LAST_TRADEABLE_DT` is not null then take `LAST_TRADEABLE_DT`, when `LAST_TRADEABLE_DT` is null then the below condition should satisfied:

```
WHEN t.opt_exer_typ = 'American'
            AND  t.mic_exch_code = 'XDMI'
            THEN t.opt_expire_dt - 1
            WHEN t.opt_exer_typ != 'American' 
            THEN t.opt_expire_dt
```

I have written below query but i am getting `last_tradedate` as null. I never want `last_tradedate` to return null.

```
  SELECT
    t.opt_exer_typ,
    t.mic_exch_code,
    t.ID_BB_GLOBAL,    
    t.LAST_TRADEABLE_DT,    
    t.OPT_EXER_TYP,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN t.LAST_TRADEABLE_DT is not null  
            THEN t.LAST_TRADEABLE_DT                     
            WHEN t.LAST_TRADEABLE_DT IS NULL 
            AND  t.opt_exer_typ = 'American'
            AND  t.mic_exch_code = 'XDMI'
            THEN t.opt_expire_dt - 1
            WHEN t.LAST_TRADEABLE_DT IS NULL 
            AND  t.opt_exer_typ != 'American' 
            THEN t.opt_expire_dt  
        END) last_tradedate,
    t.OPT_EXPIRE_DT
FROM
    TEST_AGG t where t.ID_BB_GLOBAL = 'XXX1234';
```

Comment: Just as expected, since no case when condition was true for that row's column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the value ever to be `NULL`, then use `ELSE`.  I presume you want:

```
 (CASE WHEN t.LAST_TRADEABLE_DT is not null  
       THEN t.LAST_TRADEABLE_DT                     
       WHEN t.opt_exer_typ = 'American' AND
            t.mic_exch_code = 'XDMI'
       THEN t.opt_expire_dt - 1
       ELSE t.opt_expire_dt  
  END) last_tradedate,
```

I'm not 100% sure that is the logic you want.  Your code will return `NULL` value in the following situations:

- `opt_exer_typ = 'American' and mic_exch_code <> XDMI`
- `opt_exer_typ = 'American' and mic_exch_code IS NULL`
- `opt_exer_typ IS NULL`

(assuming the first condition is not met).